# Replace EC2 user_data with a .sh script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cloud9

I have written some code in Terraform to deploy a Cloud9 environment:

```
resource "aws_cloud9_environment_ec2" "cloud9_instance" {
  name = "cloud9-instance"
  instance_type = "t2.small"
  owner_arn = local.arn
  automatic_stop_time_minutes = 30  
  connection_type = "CONNECT_SSM"
  subnet_id = local.subnet_group
}
```

I have a script.sh that I want to run upon creating the Cloud9 instance. This script needs to replace the user_data of the associated EC2 instance of the Cloud9 instance.

How do I do this successfully while keeping "aws_cloud9_environment_ec2"? Or is this not possible?

I tried to create a new EC2 instance underneath where I was successful in replacing the user_data with the contents of my script.sh.
However, it is not possible to replace the associated EC2 instance (with the default user_data) of the Cloud9 instance with the new and improved EC2 instance (with the user_data from the script.sh)

This is the code I used to complete this:

```
data "aws_instance" "cloud9_instance_data" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:aws:cloud9:environment"
    values = [aws_cloud9_environment_ec2.cloud9_instance.id]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "modified_ec2_instance" {
  ami = data.aws_instance.cloud9_instance_data.ami
  instance_type = data.aws_instance.cloud9_instance_data.instance_type
  id = data.aws_cloud9_environment_ec2.cloud9_instance.id
  user_data = "${file("./script.sh")}"
}
```

Therefore, the only other way (as far as I know) is to replace the user_data of the associated EC2 instance when the Cloud9 instance is being created.

Comment: That does not seem possible. Why not create a custom AMI and use it for a regular EC2 instance?